# Django: warning generated when installing mysqlclient with pip / pip3

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I have the following warning when trying to install the Python package `mysqlclient` in a virtual environment the following setup:

- Python 3.4
- Django 1.9

What does the warning mean? And how can I fix it?

**Please bare in mind I am learning Django and trying to to get an MySQL database set up, so please be very verbose with your answer.**

Also bare in mind that I used `pip3` to install the package.

```
Downloading/unpacking mysqlclient (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz (79kB): 79kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/owen/src/projects/mysite/build/mysqlclient/setup.py) egg_info for package mysqlclient

Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient
    building '_mysql' extension
    clang -Wno-unused-result -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing
    In file included from _mysql.c:40:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m/Python.h:8:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m/pyconfig.h:554:9: warning: 'HAVE_MBRTOWC' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
    #define HAVE_MBRTOWC 1
            ^
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/include/mysql/my_config.h:441:9: note: previous definition is here
    #define HAVE_MBRTOWC
            ^
    1 warning generated.
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.so

Successfully installed mysqlclient
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Pip tells you `Successfully installed mysqlclient`, so unless `mysqlclient` isn't working, I wouldn't worry about it. It's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Ok that's good to know, do you know what the warning means? If so, please supply it as an answer

Comment: No, I don't know what the error means.